# Is there a way to update User profile data from an application e.g. Political View?

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if there is a way to update a piece of user info from an application, for example siblings or political views or school or place of work or any other info.

I couldn't find such functionality mentioned in the developer doc directly. I was wondering if there is a way around it.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you specified your context in your subject line. "facebook" in the tags is probably not sufficient for everyone to have any clue what you're talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the profile of a user. 
[See the list](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) of all the elements you can access and publish on facebook though app

Comment: Yes. You can publish to steam. Application editing somebody's political views doesn't sound logical.